# Swift 3: Argument labels '(forTypes:, categories:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on setting push notifications through Firebase for my application. **Swift 3**

In the AppDelegate under didFinishLaunchingOptions, I am running into an error on this line:

**Argument labels '(forTypes:, categories:)' do not match any available overloads**

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
```

**Code:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

    SKCache.sharedCache.imageCache = CustomImageCache()

    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 there is no "for"; it's `types:`, not `forTypes:`.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiusernotificationsettings/1615401-init

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I might be late.But I have a solution replace the following lines of your code

```
let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
```

With the following line

```
let userNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
```